# Epson Stylus Color 800 installation

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, printer

Im trying to install an Epson Stylus color 800 printer on a windows xp machine. I have added the printer and everything else. But the printer and  PC are not communicating. I think its a driver issue and would like to know here I can get the driver. I tried Epson but nothing for winXp

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [last official driver](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=14388&prodoid=8255&BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=Downloads&platform=Windows&x=25&y=6) was for Windows 98 and was posted on June 23rd, 2000.

It seems as though your printer is quite old, and no longer officially supported by Epson.

**However**, it seems that Windows XP comes with the required drivers:

1. Click Start, then click on Printers & Faxes
2. Click on Add a Printer
3. At Welcome screen click Next
4. Select Local Printer (if printer is attached directly to computer) and click Next
5. Choose LPT1 (in most situations) or a different port if not LPT1 then click Next
6. Select Epson in left window
7. Select Epson Stylus COLOR 800 ESC/ P2 in right window
8. Click Next
9. Type name for printer or accept default name
10. Click No to Do you want to print test page.
11. Click Finish
12. Test printer by sending a print job to printer.

[Source](http://forums.driverguide.com/showthread.php?t=2312)

Answer (score 0):

I used an Epson Stylus Colour 800 with XP for several years without issue.  I used the XP drivers without problem.  Are you using an IEEE-1284 certified cable?  It will be labeled on the cable.  Older paralell cables can have issues with the 800.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cable, i've the same and running on xp without problems.